# serial numbers in a launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and I am trying to create a launch file to start two motor controllers, roscore, and some other nodes. I have two motor controllers that are identical except for their serial number. When using the terminal I would type (each in its own terminal),

> rosrun pololu_smc_driver smc_driver_node __name:=r_controller _smc_serial:="3800-6F06-3055-3932-7560-0343"

> rosrun pololu_smc_driver smc_driver_node __name:=l_controller _smc_serial:="3800-6B06-3055-3932-4160-0343"

Doing that would make two nodes, one named  "r_controller" using the device with the serial number of" 3800-6F06-3055-3932-7560-0343"
and the other node being "l_controller" with its serial number. **How do I do that same thing in the launch file?** What would that translate to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58634/serial-numbers-in-a--launch-file./) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, take a look at the XML spec for roslaunch files: http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

For your specific case, you'll want  tags that specify a name, and parameter tags for the serial numbers. Something like:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="pololu_smc_driver" type="smc_driver_node" name="r_controller">
        <param name="smc_serial" value="3800-6F06-3055-3932-7560-0343"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Along with a similar  tag for your left motor controller.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-03-20**:
I tried   " 



</launch
but when I tried to run it, it returns "Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 5, column 3""

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-20**:
You're closing your  tag prematurely; don't do that.  In particular, /> at the end of the tag specifies a self-closing tag, which is not what you want.

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-03-20**:

<node name="r_controller" pkg="pololu_smc_driver"  type="smc_driver_node"

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 2

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-03-20**:
as you can tell, I have no clue what I am dong.
I looked at "http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML" but it did not help much. I am trying to start two nodes, one that uses a specific device with a serial number of"XX-XX"

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-20**:
Updated my example. I suggest you go read an XML tutorial to get a better grasp of how XML tags and nesting work: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XML.html

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thank you so much. That works perfect. thanks for the link as well.